# Difference between `system:index` and `system:time_start` properties in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, date

If I want to know the date of image acquisition, would it be the `system:index` or `system:time_start` property?

I'm afraid I have been created a mess and used wrong dates.

For example, if I have this list, is the date that is referenced by the red arrow the acquisition date or the publication date?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to use the `system:time_start` property if you want the acquisition date. The `index` can contain a lot of extra information, which depending on the sensor, describes path/row combinations, processing level, etc.

I think the red arrow indicates the date in your case, but check it on the website from the data provider if you want to be sure:

https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-1-sar/naming-conventions

Comment: Also note that you can format the unix time, which often represents `system:time_start`, to a more human-readable format using: `image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')`, for instance.